# rest-assured expected doesn't match

Tags: web-services, rest, rest-assured

I try

```
@Test
public void testGetSingleUser() {
    given().expect().
        statusCode(200).contentType(ContentType.JSON).
        body("_testingString", equalTo("got it")).when().
        get("http://localhost:8080/getIt");
}
```

But always got this error message

> java.lang.AssertionError : JSON path _testingString dosen't match.
>
> Expected : "got it" got : [got it]

how to ignore "" and [] problem
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note:** This is untested code snippet but while looking at your error trace it may help you.

try

```
equalTo(Arrays.asList("got it"))
```

instead of

```
equalTo("got it")
```

Comment: if I try to use int type, it seems not work well... Expected <[1]>, but got [1]

Comment: did you put int value inside array?

Comment: private List<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();

Model w1 = new Model("got it",1);

Comment: your this code did not gave me any clue. if possible then provide more code then i will may help you because your these two line did not seems harmful to me

Comment: Sor I try to copy most of my code here  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643260/rest-assured-unit-testing-int-type-doesnt-match

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, @Pedro Henrique , You can pop elements from arrays and than you can compare with each item without `Arrays.asList()` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a error saying, same like that:

> JSON path total doesn't match.
> Expected: 2000
> Actual: <[2000]>

It means that your result(Actual:) is coming inside an array.

Hence, you should use a rest-assured-command(for example, ***hasItem***) that verifies values 'inside an array'.

My code below illustrate a solution for this situation:

```java
    RestAssuredWebTestClient

         .given()
         .webTestClient(mockedWebClient)
         .queryParam("cost", 1000)

         .when()
         .get(TEMPL_AGGREG_DATE)

         .then()
         .log()
         .everything()

         .statusCode(OK.value())
         .body("_id", hasItem(project2.getStartDate()))
         .body("total", hasItem((int)project2.getEstimatedCost()))
         .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("contracts/aggregations/CostsGroupByStartDate.json"))
    ;
```